# Problems changing another cell's value on the same line dynamically with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I'm trying to make a numeric value of one cell increment by clicking a button in another cell on the same row. I am using HTML5 and JQuery. Follow the code:

```js
function increment() {
    var amount = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').find('input[type="number"]').val();
    alert(amount);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th colspan="3">Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>X</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs">-</button></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>                                
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs" onclick="increment()">+</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, alert () only shows me "undefined". Someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your problem are the white space nodes between the `<td>`s. So `nth-child(3)` would return a different node you don't expect.

However, there is only one input as far as I see, so why not just try to find that one:

```
function increment() {
    var amount = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="number"]').val();
    alert(amount);
}
```

Also, your `this` won't work that way, try changing your HTML like this:

```
<td><button class="btn btn-xs" onclick="increment">+</button></td>
```

(onclick-handler without parentheses)

Comment: Oh wait, I see something different, updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code a little bit.
Hopefully this helps you.
I have added a click handler to the element which invokes a function when clicked on it.

```js
$(".increment").click(function( event ) {
  var amount = event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].children[0].value;
//you can use this line of code also
//var amount = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="number"]').val();
  alert(amount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th colspan="3">Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>X</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs">-</button></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>                                
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs increment">+</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```